# Unable to understand Java wildcards usage?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have the following code snippet

```
Number n=new Integer(2);
```

then when I use the code ,its shows an error

```
Class<Number> hi=n.getClass(); //type mismatch error
```

but if below code works fine

```
Class<? extends Number> hi=n.getClass();
```

Why is it so ? Please explain in some simple & precise words.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the class of an `Integer` is `Class<Integer>` which is different from `Class<Number>`. Because `n` can contain any kind of `Number`, its class can be any class that extends `Number`.

Comment: If you are like me and not able to understand what difference it makes, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21351277/2775450) which explains why `? extends Something` matters.